# Rails 3 application on main domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, .htaccess

I have domain www.ecotechno.lv. I want to link this domain with my RoR application.

I have done like this:

uploaded my app in /rails_apps folder

created symlink:

```
ln -s ~/rails_apps/ecotechno/public ~/public_html/ecotechno
```

Populated /rails_apps/ecotechno/public folders .htacces file with:
PassengerAppRoot /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/ecotechno/

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
Options -MultiViews
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
#Set this to whatever environment you'll be running in
RailsEnv development
RackBaseURI /
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems
</IfModule>
```

This is done by folowing hosting company's guide!

Now when I browse www.ecotechno.lv where it should start my rails app. it shows filesystem and that **ecotechno** symlink. When I click it gives error:

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
Error message:
Could not find rename-1.0.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

But why I can't start my app in first place after browsing ecotechno.lv ? You can check [www.ecotechno.lv](http://www.ecotechno.lv) if it can help.

Thanks in advance!

```
ecotec11@ecotechno.lv [~]# ls -l ~/rails_apps/ecotechno/public
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  3 ecotec11 ecotec11 4096 Sep 27 14:30 ./
drwxr-xr-x 13 ecotec11 ecotec11 4096 Jul 24 02:39 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 ecotec11 ecotec11  301 Sep 27 14:27 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 ecotec11 ecotec11  728 Feb  5  2014 404.html
-rw-r--r--  1 ecotec11 ecotec11  711 Feb  5  2014 422.html
-rw-r--r--  1 ecotec11 ecotec11  643 Feb  5  2014 500.html
-rw-r--r--  1 ecotec11 ecotec11    0 Feb  5  2014 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--  1 ecotec11 ecotec11  204 Feb  5  2014 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x  5 ecotec11 ecotec11 4096 Jun  9 11:38 system/
```

Comment: Did you do a bundle install? Looks like the required gem is not installed on your machine.

Comment: @brahmana I bundled it, but that error is ok. But I don't understand why it don't show it when I browse ecotechno.lv

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `when I browser ecotechno.lv`. I just tried `http://ecotechno.lv/ecotechno/` and `http://www.ecotechno.lv/ecotechno/` and for both of them I see the same error. The gem is not found. Are you sure the gems are installed to /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems ? Try `bundle show rename` from the app directory to see if the gem is actually installed. Also try `gem list --local rename*`

Comment: gem is not the problem, because I need to start my app on www.ecotechno.lv not in www.ecotechno.lv/ecotechno that happens at this momment.

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds - The config files you posted are just general Passenger setup, you need to show your sites configs as well. They should be in sites-available folder.

Comment: Specifically about making your app available at root location you should probably change your symlink to `ln -s ~/rails_apps/ecotechno/public ~/public_html` . Try that. Despite this I still think your got a problem with a missing gem. That's what the error says.. !

Comment: @brahmana I tried already your suggestion. Now It created symlink with other name, but still the same problem. root location still don't respond

Comment: Can you show us the output of `ls -l ~/rails_apps/ecotechno/public`?

Comment: @brahmana At the bottom of my question

Comment: Try setting PassengerAppRoot to /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/ecotechno/public/

Comment: @brahmana Still the same..

Comment: We are probably getting somewhat close, but I have run out of suggestions at this moment. Here are few other things you can try (but I am not sure if they will help) : 1) Disable directory listing in your Apache config 2) Put a sample index.html file in your public directory to make sure the folder mapping is correct. Beyond this you will have to wait for someone more knowledgeable (or better yet try anything else you can. Nothing to fear, there is always an undo option :) ).

Comment: @brahmana Thanks, now I got error at the root page, but that is different from previus. It can't find config.ru file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62049/discussion-between-brahmana-and-edgars-rozenfelds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all.
So I fixed this.

My solution.

1) Rails apps has to be in **../rails_apps/eco**

2)  Created symlink with this : `ln -s ~/rails_apps/eco/public ~/public_html/eco`

3) In **public_html/.htaccess**  insert this code :

```
PassengerAppRoot /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/eco/

<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
Options -MultiViews
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
#Set this to whatever environment you'll be running in
RailsEnv development
RackBaseURI /
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.ecotechno.lv$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ecotechno.lv/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^173\.254\.28\.107
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.ecotechno.lv/$1 [R=301,L]
```

4) In **rails_apps/eco/public/.htaccess** : leave it blank.

So I hope somebody it helps.